# Python: How to Import a folder as a module

Tags: python, module, pdblp

I am new to Python so bear with me.

I have recently download the pdblp module in a zip form. 
I then made some amendments that were needed to get through specific requests. So I have this folder, is there a way where I normally write `Import pdblp` that I can write `import 'F:\Sam\project\' as pdblp` or should it not be done like this?

Comment: to import it you need it on your path, so either run from that dir or dump it in you <python dir>/lib/site-packages or add it to your PYTHONPATH

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the module `pdblp` is located inside your project-directory, you can simple append your current path and then import it afterwards like so:

```
import sys
# Keep in mind that you need to escape backslashes by doubling them
sys.path.append("F:\\Sam\\project\\")

import pdblp
```

Comment: `# Keep in mind that you need to escape backslashes by doubling them` Actually you can use [`'C:/Sam/project'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953843/10811334).

Answer (score 1):

You can import folder as package not module. *.py file is itself module. If you want to import folder, you need add **init**.py file inside the folder and then it will become package then you can import